# verify: command not found exception when trying to get value from user

Tags: linux, shell-script, sendmail

**Code Explanation:** The below code is a simple script written by me to send a Installation status alert mail. It will be sent after completion of a linux software installation.
In this code, If the user accept the mail notification he will be asked to enter his mail id. Then the mail will be send to him after installation completed.

```
#!/bin/bash

#######################################
# Independent Variables and  Properties Here
#######################################
PL_EMAIL_ALERT=""
#######################################
# User to get Email Alert
#######################################
echo "This will help user to get an email of an installation status."
verify -s "Do want to send Email"
if [ "$VerAns" = "y" ]
then
    read -e -p "Enter Email ID: " PL_EMAIL_ALERT
fi
#######################################
# Sending Email Alert
#######################################
echo "Sending Mail"
if [ ${#PL_EMAIL_ALERT} -ne 0 ]
then
    mail -s "software INSTALLATION MAIL ALERT" $PL_EMAIL_ALERT <<< "message1"
fi
echo ""
echo "Final step"
echo ""
```

**Problem:** My problem is when I try to execute the code I am getting the following error.
*`verify: command not found`*
As I am very new to linux I am unable to fix this issue. Can you please help me to understand what exactly I missed.

Answer (score 1):

You can execute commands into Script if those commands are available in system.

In your case `verify` command is unavailable. Hence the error.

Either install the relevant package OR write a program/script/function by name `verify`

Answer (score 0):

The VerAns, Y/N is never read, code below helps on that. Verify Function is not in your library, you should write of your own as SHW told,

```
    #!/bin/bash

#######################################
# Independent Variables and  Properties Here
#######################################
PL_EMAIL_ALERT=""
VerAns=""
#######################################
# User to get Email Alert
#######################################
echo "This will help user to get an email of an installation status."
#verify "Do want to send Email"
read -e -p "Y/N" VerAns
if [ "$VerAns" = "y" ]
then
    read -e -p "Enter Email ID: " PL_EMAIL_ALERT
fi
#######################################
# Sending Email Alert
#######################################
echo "Sending Mail"
if [ ${#PL_EMAIL_ALERT} -ne 0 ]
then
    mail -s "software INSTALLATION MAIL ALERT" $PL_EMAIL_ALERT <<< "message1"
fi
echo ""
echo "Final step"
echo ""
```

This works perfectly...

Comment: In Bash there's no need to initialize variables before assigning to them: `echo $non_explicitly_inited_var` just expands to nothing and `read foo` will read something into a variable `foo` whether it is used before or not.

Answer (score 0):

An error message on the form `x: command not found` occurs if the `x` command is not installed or found in your system. But there real problem here is that you seem to confuse the function of `verify` with the `read` shell builtin. Looking at its [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/verify) you should see that it doesn't do what you expect it to do: it's a tool for verifying certificates.

Use `read -p` as you already have done in the other part of the script to prompt for an answer. You could shorten your script by putting the e-mail sending part inside the `if` block:

```
# ...   

read -ep "Do you want to send Email? " alert
if [[ $alert =~ [Yy] ]]; then
    read -ep "Enter Email ID: " addr
    if (( ${#addr} )); then 
        echo "Sending Email"
        mail -s "software INSTALLATION MAIL ALERT" $addr <<< "message1"
    fi
fi

# ...
```